# How to loop over boxed iterator?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

> **Note:** This question is obsolete since Rust 1.0. The `Iterator` trait now has an associated type, `Item`, instead of a type parameter and a blanket `Iterator` implementation was added for `Box<Iterator>`.

I want to define a trait method that returns an iterator. I want to avoid specifying what the actual return type is, so until we have unboxed abstract return types, I'm using trait objects. This means the method returns `Box<Iterator<A>>`. But I'm not sure how to use a boxed trait object. I can't iterate over an object of type `Box<Iterator<A>>`:

```
fn main() {
    let xs = vec![0u, 1, 2, 3];
    let boxed_iter = box xs.iter() as Box<Iterator<&uint>>;
    for x in boxed_iter {}
}
```

This errors with `"for" loop expression does not implement the "Iterator" trait`.

So my question is: How can I iterate over `Box<Iterator<A>>`. Or, more generally, how can I used boxed trait objects?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `Box<Iterator<A>>` does not itself implement the `Iterator` trait. (I'm not sure exactly why, perhaps someone else can chime in on that point.)

You could remedy this yourself with:

```
impl<A> Iterator<A> for Box<Iterator<A>> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> { self.next() }
}
```

But since neither type nor trait are defined in your crate, this is not allowed. To work around this, you could define your own sub-trait of `Iterator`, implement `Iterator<A>` for all `Box<MyIter<A>>` and then implement `MyIter<A>` for all types `I` that satisfy `Iterator<A>`:

```
trait MyIter<A> : Iterator<A> {}
impl<A, I: Iterator<A>> MyIter<A> for I {}

// This is now allowed because `MyIter` is defined in this crate.
impl<A> Iterator<A> for Box<MyIter<A>> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> { self.next() }
}
```

And you'd have to change your code to use `as Box<MyIter<&uint>>`:

```
fn main() {
    let xs = vec![0u, 1, 2, 3];
    let mut boxed_iter = box xs.iter() as Box<MyIter<&uint>>;
    for x in boxed_iter { println!("{}", x); }
}
```

(I added mutability to `boxed_iter` since it is required for iterators.)

Comment: This doesn't compile with the following error: lib.rs:9:19: 9:30 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1 [E0244]
lib.rs:9 trait MyIter<A> : Iterator<A> {}
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:9:19: 9:30 help: run `rustc --explain E0244` to see a detailed explanation
lib.rs:10:12: 10:23 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1 [E0244]
lib.rs:10 impl<A, I: Iterator<A>> MyIter<A> for I {}
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: lib.rs:10:12: 10:23 help: run `rustc --explain E0244` to see a detailed explanation
lib.rs:13:29: 13:38 error: the value of the associated type `Item` (from the trait `core::iter::Iterator`) must be specified [E0191]
lib.rs:13 impl<A> Iterator<A> for Box<MyIter<A>> {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:13:9: 13:20 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1 [E0244]
lib.rs:13 impl<A> Iterator<A> for Box<MyIter<A>> {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: It's because the code has bit-rotted. The question should no longer be relevant since `Box<Iterator>` impls `Iterator`.